# Tkinter Minesweeper

Tags: python, tkinter, minesweeper, thonny

I am creating a minesweeper game in Tkinter. The entire game is finished with the bombs and clicking; however I do not know how to make a "You Win" in the game. It doesn't have to be exact, but I want a way for the user to be able to win the game. I was thinking of "if buttons(not the bomb) are forget(), then print a messagebox saying "You Win". Any help is greatly appreciated

```
from tkinter import *#imports tkinter
from tkinter import messagebox#imports the module messagebox from tkinter
import pygame #imports the module Pygame 
sounds = pygame.mixer #allows the import of sounds a.k.a .wav files
sounds.init()#init() is called when an object is created from a class


app=Tk()#creates the app
app.geometry('250x230')#the exact size/grid of the app
app.resizable(0,0)#0,0 allows a "lock" on the app


def destroy1():# a function that destroys buttons so user cannot click on them once they click once
    b1h.place_forget()#forget() is a function that makes the script 'forget' the button existed

def destroy2():# a function that destroys buttons so user cannot click on them once they click once
    bf7.place_forget()#forget() is a function that makes the script 'forget' the button existed

def destroy3():
    b11v.place_forget()#forget() is a function that makes the script 'forget' the button existed

def destroy4():
    bf13t.place_forget()#forget() is a function that makes the script 'forget' the button existed

    
def destroy5():
    ba112.place_forget()#forget() is a function that makes the script 'forget' the button existed
    ba11.place_forget()#forget() is a function that makes the script 'forget' the button existed
    ba1.place_forget()#forget() is a function that makes the script 'forget' the button existed
    b2.place_forget()#forget() is a function that makes the script 'forget' the button existed
    ba.place_forget()#forget() is a function that makes the script 'forget' the button existed
    bf7.place_forget()#forget() is a function that makes the script 'forget' the button existed

def destroy6():
    bf1io.place_forget()#forget() is a function that makes the script 'forget' the button existed

def destroy7():
    b287.place_forget()#forget() is a function that makes the script 'forget' the button existed

def destroy71():
    b111356.place_forget()#forget() is a function that makes the script 'forget' the button existed

def destroy72():
    b11124.place_forget()#forget() is a function that makes the script 'forget' the button existed
    
def destroy73():
    bf13245.place_forget()#forget() is a function that makes the script 'forget' the button existed

def destroy74():
    b211245.place_forget()#forget() is a function that makes the script 'forget' the button existed

def destroy75():
    b21134.place_forget()#forget() is a function that makes the script 'forget' the button existed

def increase():#a function to increase font size
    fontsize= fontStyle['size']#makes a variable call fontsize
    labelExample['text'] = fontsize + 2#the label of the text is equal to the fontsize + 2
    fontStyle.configure(size=fontsize+2)#configure() is the function that allows the configuration of the fontsize

def win():
    s = sounds.Sound("Sound Effect (3).wav")#plays a selected .wav file from the folder
    s.play()#play() is the function that plays the wav.file in the tkinter
    messagebox.showinfo("Lose", "You Lose!")#displays a messagebox 
    app.destroy()#closes the tkinter window

def bomb():
    s = sounds.Sound("C.wav")#plays a selected .wav file from the folder
    s.play()#play() is the function that plays the wav.file in the tkinter
    messagebox.showinfo("Lose", "You Lose!")#displays a messagebox 
    app.destroy()#closes the tkinter window

def instruct():#A function
    s = sounds.Sound("07_button7.wav")#plays a selected .wav file from the folder
    s.play()#play() is the function that plays the wav.file in the tkinter
    messagebox.showinfo("Instruction",  "The numbers on the board represent how many bombs are adjacent to a square. For example, if a square has a 2 on it, then there are 2 bombs next to that square. The bombs could be above, below, right left, or diagonal to the square. Avoid all the bombs  to win Minesweeper.")    

Label(app, text = "Mini Minesweeper", font=("Courier",15)).pack()#
Label(app, text = "There are two bombs", font=("Courier",10)).pack()#


#row 1
b787 = Button(app, text = 'Help\n', width = 6, height=2 , command=instruct) # a button that displays an answer in a text, and when pressed it activates incorrect()
b787.place (relx=0.01, rely=0.85, anchor =W)#rely and relx controls the format where the button is placed


b1 = Button(app, text = '', width = 6 ) # a button that displays an answer in a text, and when pressed it activates incorrect()
b1.place (relx=0.10, rely=0.30, anchor =W)#rely and relx controls the format where the button is placed
b1h = Button(app, text = '', width = 6, command=lambda : [destroy1(), bomb()] ) # a button that displays an answer in a text, and when pressed it activates incorrect()
b1h.place (relx=0.10, rely=0.30, anchor =W)#rely and relx controls the format where the button is placed



bf = Button(app, text = '1' , width = 6) # a button that displays an answer in a text, and when pressed it activates incorrect()
bf.place (relx=0.30 , rely=0.30, anchor =W)#rely and relx controls the format where the button is placed
bf7 = Button(app, text = '', width = 6, command=destroy2) # a button that displays an answer in a text, and when pressed it activates incorrect()
bf7.place (relx=0.30 , rely=0.30, anchor =W)#rely and relx controls the format where the button is placed



b2 = Button(app, text = '', width = 6, command=destroy5)# a button that displays an answer in a text, and when pressed it activates correct()
b2.place(relx=0.50 , rely=0.30, anchor =W)#rely and relx controls the format where the button is placed



ba = Button(app, text = '', width = 6, command=destroy5)# a button that displays an answer in a text, and when pressed it activates correct()
ba.place(relx=0.70, rely=0.30, anchor =W)#rely and relx controls the format where the button is placed

#row 2
b11 = Button(app, text = '2', width = 6 ) # a button that displays an answer in a text, and when pressed it activates incorrect()
b11.place (relx=0.10, rely=0.40, anchor =W)#rely and relx controls the format where the button is placed
b11v = Button(app, text = '', width = 6, command= destroy3 ) # a button that displays an answer in a text, and when pressed it activates incorrect()
b11v.place (relx=0.10, rely=0.40, anchor =W)#rely and relx controls the format where the button is placed



bf1 = Button(app, text = '2', width = 6) # a button that displays an answer in a text, and when pressed it activates incorrect()
bf1.place (relx=0.30 , rely=0.40, anchor =W)#rely and relx controls the format where the button is placed
bf1io = Button(app, text = '', width = 6, command=destroy6) # a button that displays an answer in a text, and when pressed it activates incorrect()
bf1io.place (relx=0.30 , rely=0.40, anchor =W)#rely and relx controls the format where the button is placed



b21 = Button(app, text = '1', width = 6)# a button that displays an answer in a text, and when pressed it activates correct()
b21.place(relx=0.50 , rely=0.40, anchor =W)#rely and relx controls the format where the button is placed
b287 = Button(app, text = '', width = 6, command= destroy7)# a button that displays an answer in a text, and when pressed it activates correct()
b287.place(relx=0.50 , rely=0.40, anchor =W)#rely and relx controls the format where the button is placed



ba1 = Button(app, text = '', width = 6, command=destroy5)# a button that displays an answer in a text, and when pressed it activates correct()
ba1.place(relx=0.70, rely=0.40, anchor =W)#rely and relx controls the format where the button is placed

#row3

b111 = Button(app, text = '1', width = 6 ) # a button that displays an answer in a text, and when pressed it activates incorrect()
b111.place (relx=0.10, rely=0.50, anchor =W)#rely and relx controls the format where the button is placed
b111356 = Button(app, text = '', width = 6, command=destroy71 ) # a button that displays an answer in a text, and when pressed it activates incorrect()
b111356.place (relx=0.10, rely=0.50, anchor =W)#rely and relx controls the format where the button is placed


bf13 = Button(app, text = '', width =6) # a button that displays an answer in a text, and when pressed it activates incorrect()
bf13.place (relx=0.30 , rely=0.50, anchor =W)#rely and relx controls the format where the button is placed
bf13t = Button(app, text = '', width =6, command=lambda : [destroy4(), bomb()] ) # a button that displays an answer in a text, and when pressed it activates incorrect()
bf13t.place (relx=0.30 , rely=0.50, anchor =W)#rely and relx controls the format where the button is placed




b211 = Button(app, text = '1', width = 6)# a button that displays an answer in a text, and when pressed it activates correct()
b211.place(relx=0.50 , rely=0.50, anchor =W)#rely and relx controls the format where the button is placed
b21134 = Button(app, text = '', width = 6, command=destroy75)# a button that displays an answer in a text, and when pressed it activates correct()
b21134.place(relx=0.50 , rely=0.50, anchor =W)#rely and relx controls the format where the button is placed


ba11 = Button(app, text = '', width = 6, command=destroy5)# a button that displays an answer in a text, and when pressed it activates correct()
ba11.place(relx=0.70, rely=0.50, anchor =W)#rely and relx controls the format where the button is placed

#row 4

b1112 = Button(app, text = '1', width = 6 ) # a button that displays an answer in a text, and when pressed it activates incorrect()
b1112.place (relx=0.10, rely=0.60, anchor =W)#rely and relx controls the format where the button is placed
b11124 = Button(app, text = '', width = 6, command= destroy72 ) # a button that displays an answer in a text, and when pressed it activates incorrect()
b11124.place (relx=0.10, rely=0.60, anchor =W)#rely and relx controls the format where the button is placed



bf132 = Button(app, text = '1', width = 6) # a button that displays an answer in a text, and when pressed it activates incorrect()
bf132.place (relx=0.30 , rely=0.60, anchor =W)#rely and relx controls the format where the button is placed
bf13245 = Button(app, text = '', width = 6, command= destroy73) # a button that displays an answer in a text, and when pressed it activates incorrect()
bf13245.place (relx=0.30 , rely=0.60, anchor =W)#rely and relx controls the format where the button is placed

b2112 = Button(app, text = '1', width = 6)# a button that displays an answer in a text, and when pressed it activates correct()
b2112.place(relx=0.50 , rely=0.60, anchor =W)#rely and relx controls the format where the button is placed
b211245 = Button(app, text = '', width = 6, command= destroy74)# a button that displays an answer in a text, and when pressed it activates correct()
b211245.place(relx=0.50 , rely=0.60, anchor =W)#rely and relx controls the format where the button is placed

ba112 = Button(app, text = '', width =6, command=destroy5)# a button that displays an answer in a text, and when pressed it activates correct()
ba112.place(relx=0.70, rely=0.60, anchor =W)#rely and relx controls the format where the button is placed
```

Comment: You might want to rewrite the code using `for` loops. It's hard to debug when you have that many widgets and function that you have to keep track of

Answer (score 0):

You can show the message using [tkinter.messagebox](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.messagebox.html)

This will look more appealing and you dont have to reframe your existing buttons

`tkinter.messagebox.showinfo(title="Result", message="You Won !!!", **options)`